# Is there a way to default Richfaces to use long-polling for push instead of WebSockets?

Tags: java, jsf, websocket, richfaces, long-polling

I've seen answers for older versions of Richfaces to put `richfaces.Push.transport = "long-polling` in the JavaScript, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. Especially when using packed.js (`org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled=true`). Is there another way to have it default to long-polling instead of defaulting to WebSockets and falling back on long-polling?

Answer (score 1):

The current setting is in `RichFaces.push.options.transport` though I am not sure you can change it on the fly.